# Capture shell script output properly in Perl

Tags: perl, shell, output

First, I know that this question was asked many times, but no solution found here seems to help me :/

I try to make an interface in Perl that can launch some shell scripts.

My idea was to get shell script output (stdout and stderr) and show it in live on another frame on my main window.

The problem :

The output is not kept in a variable, it's show immediatly on the middle of the screen, and I don't understand this behavior..

Here is a little screenshot of the result :

*-deleted-*

The goal is to show the output in the "Progress" frame ; I tried many Perl method to get this  worked, but I fail every time...

Here is some examples of what I tried :

```
sub launch_child(@)
{
    my $pid = open(KID, '-|');
    die "fork: $!" unless defined($pid);
    if($pid) {
        my $output;
        while (<KID>) {
            $process_tracking->text($process_tracking->text() .  "$_");
        }
        close(KID);
    } else {
        exec @_;
    }
}
```

or

```
sub launch_child()
{
    my $sel = IO::Select->new();
    open my $fh, '-|', './shell_script.sh';
    while (<$fh>) {
        $process_tracking->text($process_tracking->text() .  "$_" );
    }
    close $fh;
    $sel->add($fh);
    push( @selects , $sel );
}
```

Thanks to all Perl experts which can help me to achieve this ;)

**EDIT :**

I find a way to do this (thanks to choroba for the "stderr" clue) :

```
my @selects = ();

sub launch_child()
{
    my $sel = IO::Select->new();
    open my $fh, '-|', './shell_script.sh 2>&1';
    $sel->add($fh);
    push( @selects , $sel );
}
sub read_from_child()
{
    if (scalar @selects > 0) {
        for my $sel (@selects) {
            if (my @readers = $sel->can_read(0)) {
                for my $fh (@readers) {
                    my $rv = sysread($fh, my $buf, 64*1024);
                    if (!$rv) {
                        $sel->remove($fh);
                        close($fh);
                        next;
                    }
                    $process_tracking->text($process_tracking->text().$buf);
                    $process_tracking->cursor_to_end();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

while (1) {
    $cui->{-read_timeout} = 0;
    $cui->do_one_event();
    read_from_child();
    sleep 0.1;
}
```

Screen shot of new result :

*-deleted-*

Now, I'm asking why the colors in the shell script isn't evaluated : `echo -ne [...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correctly reading the STDOUT of the process, but the STDERR goes freely directly to the screen. See [perlipc](http://p3rl.org/perlipc) for details.

Comment: Not sure to understand what to do exaclty... But I try to redirect STDERR in STDOUT, it works but it seems to fill a buffer before writing anything ; I write "$| = 1" but it doesn't change anything :/

Comment: @Doubidou: What do you mean by "fill a buffer"?

Comment: I mean, it waits until all the shell script was executed before showing anything ; but there's just a second ago, I found a method, by sending $fh in a IO:Select, and execute a separated loop that read the Select ; it works :) Ugly, bu tit works... Now I have to found why the ANSI colors of my shell script are not evaluated in the Perl script..